# How to integrate db4o and autofac for my Model objects?

Tags: mvvm, ioc-container, autofac, db4o

I can see how I can instantiate objects of classes using autofac, and then pass these to db4o for storage. When it's time for me to retrieve the object instances from db4o, how do I register the objects with autofac?

I was originally planning on using db4o's MSBuild tool to implement transparent activation/persistence, but it looks like that I may have to manually implement the IActivatable interface for all my Model objects so that I can put in extra code in `IActivatable::Bind()` to register `this` pointers as they are activated.

To make matters worst, I foresee that the implementation of `IActivatable::Bind()` will have to access a Singleton of the current Autofac lifetime scope to do the registration against. Obviously, I can't pass in the current lifetime scope to the object instance that db4o is activating. As bad as passing the scope around is, I can imagine the groans from people considering sticking the current life scope in a public Singleton.

An alternative seems to be to implement db4o's Type Handlers and intercept object instantiation at that point, but that seems like undoing any gains I had of using db4o for storing objects.

Or did I just go a little too crazy with the idea of using autofac to instantiate all objects? (e.g. I've got a hammer and everything looked like a nail.) Should Model objects just be instantiated by plain old 'new' and whatever magic that db4o uses? In other words, use autofac only with my View, ViewModel and Controller objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend to replace every 'new' with an Autofac instantiation. My rule of thumb is that I when a object needs complex dependencies (not simple collections, core CLR types, other simple objects), then I let Autofac do the work. Simple domain object I usually just use the new operator or a create a factory.

I'm not 100% sure if I get your question right. You want to bind some service to your domain models when they are instantiated? Well then I recommend to use [events](http://developer.db4o.com/Documentation/Reference/db4o-8.0/net35/reference/Content/advanced_topics/callbacks/event_registry_api.htm). You can use the db4o events to detect when an object gets stored, activated, etc. In such a event listener you can use the current Autofac scope to pass additional services.

Btw. the IActivatable::Bind() stuff is already called by db4o. You don't need to do anything else.

In general I would try to properly scope everything and not misuse Autofac as a service-locater.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me towards events, I'll take a look. It's not the commit part, that I have problems with as I noted in my question. It's the loading part that I have problems with. If I do nothing and just use TA, then I'll have objects that get loaded into memory that are not registered with autofac. I know that IActivatable::Bind() is called by db4o on load, that's why I was looking at using it as an opportunity to register the object with autofac. As I also noted, I wanted to avoid using autofac as a service locator.

Comment: Looking at the Event Registry API, I see that there's an Activated event. Even better, this meshes well with the domain event concept as suggested by Nick. It still looks like I'll need to have the autofac IContainer available to my Activated handler. On the up side, this looks less onerous than having to touch the code for each of my domain objects.

Answer (score 3):

There's no "true path" :) but the recommended approach here is to get away from using services directly in the domain model, and instead dispatch 'Domain Events' to IoC-enabled handlers.

Jimmy Bogard has a good number of posts on the topic - there's an example for StructureMap that you should be able to adapt for Autofac: http://lostechies.com/jimmybogard/2010/08/04/container-friendly-domain-events/

(BTW, coincidentally, I have an Autofac-based example implementation that I'm cleaning up to release in the next few weeks.)

Comment: Using domain events looks like a promising approach, but that still requires that I be able to hook every object load from the database to fire the event. So much for transparent activation, it's not so transparent anymore if I have to "handle" the activation, if only to register the instance with autofac.

Comment: @Gamlor's answer below about using db4o's events meshes well with the idea of using domain events. I'll still have to "handle" each activation, but at least I won't have touch the code for each domain object. I'll just have this central Activated event handler that gets called. I still don't see how to get away from having the pass around the autofac IContainer, be it in the DomainEvent.Container or in my Activated event handler code written as a lambda.